# Python : If statement within a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I wrote a program, which keeps rolling a "num" sided die until it reaches the maximal roll which is the number you write as "num". However, if it happens that the first roll is the number, the program does not say "You landed on your number!" as it should. Here is the code

```
import random

num = () #put the number here#
i = random.randint(1,num)

while i != num:
    print(i)
    print("Not lucky")
    i = random.randint(1,num)
    if i == num:
        print("You landed on your number!")
```

Again, if the roll equals the number choice, I get "Process finished with exit code 0", not the text I want. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the final print, outside of the `while` loop, as you're always land there

```
num = 5  # put the number here#
i = random.randint(1, num)
while i != num:
    print("Not lucky,", i, "isn't the one")
    i = random.randint(1, num)
print("You landed on your number!")
```

Answer (score 0):

what if something like that?

```
import random

num = int(input('Put your number: '))
i = random.randint(1, num)

while True:
    if i == num:
        print("You landed on your number!")
        print(num)
        break
    else:
        print(i)
        print("Not lucky")
        i = random.randint(1, num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import random

num = (2) #put the number here#
i = random.randint(1,num)

while i != num:
    i = random.randint(1,num)
    if i != num:
        print(i, "Not lucky")


print(i, "You landed on your number!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

num = #put the number here#

while True:
    i = random.randint(1,num)
    print(i)
    if i == num:
        print("You landed on your number!")
        break
    print("Not lucky")
```